# Is a PostgreSQL trigger asynchronous?

Tags: postgresql

Sorry but I am new to SQL triggers and need some help.

I am after creating a trigger on `UPDATE` to one of my PostgreSQL tables.  The trigger calls `DELETE` on a different table.   My question is:  Is the trigger portion of the request asynchronous or synchronous to the `UPDATE` request?

For more information here are my trigger and function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION expire_table() RETURNS trigger AS $expire_table$
  BEGIN
     DELETE FROM object_store WHERE p_time < NOW() - INTERVAL '6 months';
     RETURN NEW;
  END;
$expire_table$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER expire_table_trigger
  AFTER UPDATE ON objects
EXECUTE PROCEDURE expire_table();
```

My hope is that the trigger portion is asynchronous or that there is a way of making it so.

Comment: You are creating a function calling a trigger in that function and finally executing a procedure. What do you wanna do?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I think you misread the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Yes. Mistake accepted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The trigger is always executed in the same transaction as the statement, so it must needs be synchronous. No way around that.

Instead of a trigger, you might consider using a queue that a worker process handles asynchronously or an architecture that uses `LISTEN/NOTIFY`.